# Classic "Back To Reality" Effect

Tags: sound-design, effects

Hi everyone,

I'm working on a project where there is slow motion scene during an intense moment and the character is "sucked" back to reality.

I've tried hitting the ambiences in hard at the end of the sequence but since there isn't much actually going on in the scene there isn't anything in the room I can really use to make it big enough.

That being said I want to try use a classic suck back effect. How do you create it? Is it just white noise with some envelopes?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is one of the more difficult design tasks I've ran into.
It sounds like there's no actual clue in the visual cut that allows for a snap back to reality.
In these situations it is mostly trial and error for finding the right moment, the length volume or filter slopes or reverb vs direct sound.
You can of course also try to sell it with a sound that has either a connection with the character (ie. a memory) or with the context (office > telephone ring or street > car horn, etc). 
But this will take some time, so be prepared to think a bit about it and experiment.
And don't fix this stuff with an inexperienced director around, they tend to get anxious when you do not have thinks totally figured out yet.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A classic way to make the "suck" sound is to find something that has a sharp hit and a decent ring off, and then reverse it... Try doors, drums, metal bangs -especially something that's relevant to the scene and story- reverse it, and play it under the transition. Volume is a big deal here... you USUALLY want to feel it more than hear it, but always depends on the director.